# Ubuntu 16.04 will not completely boot

Tags: boot, 16.04, boot-repair

I have Ubuntu 16.04 installed on a hard drive that exclusively runs Ubuntu.  Therefore it is not dual boot system.

I had a sort of crash in which I had to press the reset button.  When the system rebooted, I did see the GNU GRUB window and selected Ubuntu as usual.  But instead of booting, I saw the following on a black screen:

```
Busybox v1.22.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.22.0-15ubuntu1) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

(initramfs)
```

I did use boot-repair and after running, it claimed that it had made repairs.  But when I then tried to reboot, I had the same problem.

I also selected Advanced Options in the GRUB screen and then one of the recovery mode options from the list.  But that left me in the middle of no where as I didn't know what else to do.  I was expecting to get a GUI window with a list of options to try, but that didn't happen.

The system is installed on a fully LUKS encrypted disk so I don't know if I can use the LIVE CD to repair this.

Does anyone have any suggestions beside reinstall Ubuntu again?

Answer (score 1):

To check the file system on your Ubuntu partition...

- boot to the GRUB menu
- choose Advanced Options
- choose Recovery mode
- choose Root access
- at the # prompt, type `sudo fsck -f /`
- repeat the fsck command if there were errors
- type `reboot

If for some reason you can't do the above...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- start `gparted` and determine which /dev/sdaX is your Ubuntu partition
- quit `gparted`
- open a `terminal` window
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdaX` # replacing X with the number you found earlier
- repeat the fsck command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

Comment: Hello heynnema and thanks for a quick reply.  I am stuck on the instruction to choose Root access.  I do not have a # prompt.  The only prompt that I have is (initramfs).  I can type help at this prompt to get a list of built-in commands, and sudo, root and fsck are not among them.  If you can tell me how to get root access from the (initramfs) prompt, I'm sure I will be able to take this further.  By the way, after I select recovery mode, I am only left with a black screen that looks like a terminal window but for the fact that there is no # prompt.

Comment: @Justa I've updated my answer above. Before trying the update, try typing `exit` or `quit` to the initramfs prompt... see what happens.

Comment: @heynnema `fsck`won't work just like that because of the encrypted partitions: http://serverfault.com/questions/375090/using-fsck-to-check-and-repair-luks-encrypted-disk

Comment: Let me add something else.

After Advanced Options following: (Attempt to read block from filesystem resulted in hort read).

Error reading block 3708754 (Attempt to read block from filesystem resulted in hort read).
/dev/mapper/ubu-root:UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY.  (i.e., without -a or -p options)
fsck exited with status code 4 done.
Failure: file system check of the root filesystem failed The root filesystem on /dev/mapper/ubu-root requires a manual fsck.

I have two partitions on this hard drive: 
/dev/sda1 ext2          boot 
/dev/sda2 crypt-luks lvm

Comment: According to @CelticWarrior link, LUKS and LVM require a different fsck procedure. Check out that link.